# MySQL JOIN one of the rows from second table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables: one for the restaurants containing general information, and the other - for it's description translations. The second table has such columns:

`restaurant_id`, `description`, `language`

The client application makes request for the list of restaurants, and passes the **language** it wants the result for. So now I need to JOIN those 2 tables. Everything would be easy, if each restaurant had description in each of available languages, but it does not. Some restaurants are missing descriptions in some languages.

So in case if the description is missing in selected language, I should return a description in **default** language (let it be `eng` for example).

So the question is how can I JOIN the tables the way that if the description in selected language is available - join with it, otherwise - join with `eng`?

Comment: what you have try for that ..? and which type of output you want share your table definition and output you want..!

Comment: where is your tried query and output you need ..?

Comment: Most likely you are looking for an `outer join`, perhaps with `coalesce`.  Sample data and desired results would be helpful though.

Comment: @Dr.Strange the issue with SQL is that it can be quite difficult to turn an abstract concept or description of requirements into a working query (unless you're good with relational algebra). I think OP has shown they understand the problem domain but are just unsure how to translate it to actual code. Some sample data and desired output would be good to have though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is *left join* onto your *translations* table with the chosen language and also *inner join* onto *translations* again with the default language.

Then you can use [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to chose the first, non-null value. For example

```
SELECT r.name, COALESCE(t.description, t_default.description) as description
FROM restaurant r
LEFT JOIN translation t ON r.id = t.restaurant_id
  AND t.lang = 'fr' -- the chosen language
INNER JOIN translation t_default ON r.id = t_default.restaurant_id
  AND t_default.lang = 'en' -- the default language
```

Demo ~ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa68c0/1

---

I've used an `INNER JOIN` for the default language to ensure there's a value to display. If you're fine with a possible `NULL` result, change it to a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: this is totally and 100% what I have been looking for. I did not know about `COALESCE` existing. And about the demo you provided - it made me totally understand how it works. The best answer I ever got on SO.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution is to use temporary table to select IDs of the restaurants which have translation, and then using UNION to combine the restaurants with translation + all default restaurants excluding restaurant IDs having translations:

Create temporary table with IDs:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS existing_ids AS (SELECT r.id FROM restaurant r JOIN translation t ON r.id = t.restaurant_id WHERE t.lang = 'fr');
```

Select rows having translation:

```
SELECT r.name, t.description FROM restaurant r JOIN translation t ON r.id = t.restaurant_id WHERE t.lang = 'fr'
```

Union with rows with default translation excluding IDs from the temporary table:

```
UNION 
SELECT r.name, t.description FROM restaurant r JOIN translation t ON r.id = t.restaurant_id WHERE t.lang = 'en' AND id not in (SELECT id from existing_ids)
```

Demo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3e66dc/1